# how to explicitly write two references in ruamel.yaml

Tags: ruamel.yaml

If I have multiple references and when I write them to a YAML file using ruaml.yaml from Python I get:

```
  <<: [*name-name, *help-name]
```

but instead I would prefer to have

```
<<: *name-name
<<: *help-name
```

Is there an option to achieve this while writing to the file?

**UPDATE**

```
descriptions:
  - &description-one-ref
    description: >

helptexts:
  - &help-one
    help_text: |

questions:
  - &question-one
    title: "title test"
    reference: "question-one-ref"
    field: "ChoiceField"
    choices:
      - "Yes"
      - "No"
    required: true
    <<: *description-one-ref
    <<: *help-one
    riskvalue_max: 10
    calculations:
      - conditions:
          - comparator: "equal"
            value: "Yes"
        actions:
          - riskvalue: 0
      - conditions:
          - comparator: "equal"
            value: "No"
        actions:
          - riskvalue: 10
```

Currently I'm reading such a file and modify specific values within python and then want to write it back. When I'm writing I'm getting the issue that the references are as list and not as outlined.

That means the workflow is as: I'm reading the doc via

```
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
with open('test.yaml') as f:
    data = yaml.load(f)

for k in data.keys():
    if k == 'questions':
        q = data.get(k)
        for i in range(0, len(q)):
            q[i]['title'] = "my new title"

f.close()
g = open('new_file.yaml', 'w')
yaml(data)
g.close()
```

Comment: Is that just for aesthetics or do you need to do some YAML parsing with non-standard tools that would make that easier? If the latter it is possible to hook into the round-trip-parser to extract that information.

Comment: @Anthon I need exactly this for a non-standard tool. How can I hook that into the round-trip-parser? I've added a bounty and more than happy to assign it to you once you updated your answer. many thanks for your help

Comment: I will be happy to look at this, even without bounty. Can you update your question with what you already  have that gives you the first example (i.e. that what get). I can probably come up with something that produces that output, but starting with your program and/or data, an answer will closer match what you already have.

Comment: @Anthon I've added what I'm done. The thing is, I have a file with multireferences in that format and need to alter certain values in it. The output needs to be the same, which means I the list will make it break. I've added a toy example. many thx. really appreciate your work with the package!

Comment: Answer has been updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such option, as it would lead to an invalid YAML file.

The `<<` is a mapping key, for which the value is interpreted
specially assuming the parser implements to the [language independent
merge key specification](http://yaml.org/type/merge.html). And a mapping key must be unique
according to the [YAML specification](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2764044):

> The content of a mapping node is an unordered set of key: value node
>     pairs, with the restriction that each of the keys is unique.

That `ruamel.yaml` (< 0.15.75) doesn't throw an error on such
duplicate key is a [bug](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml/issues/251/). On duplicate normal keys, `ruamel.yaml`
does throw an error. The bug is inherited from PyYAML (which is not
specification conformant, and does not throw an error even on
duplicate normal keys).

---

However with a little pre- and post-processing what you want to do can
be easily achieved. The trick is to make the YAML valid before parsing
by making the offending duplicate `<<` keys unique (but recognisable)
and then, when writing the YAML back to file, substituting these
unique keys by `<<: *` again.  In the following the first occurence of
`<<: *` is replaced by `[<<, 0]:`, the second by `[<<, 1]:` etc.

The `*` needs to be part of the substitution, as there are no anchors in
the document for those aliases.

```
import sys
import subprocess
import ruamel.yaml

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
yaml.indent(sequence=4, offset=2)

class DoubleMergeKeyEnabler(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pat = '<<: '  # could be at the root level mapping, so no leading space
        self.r_pat = '[<<, {}]: '   # probably not using sequences as keys
        self.pat_nr = -1

    def convert(self, doc):
        while self.pat in doc:
            self.pat_nr += 1
            doc = doc.replace(self.pat, self.r_pat.format(self.pat_nr), 1)
        return doc

    def revert(self, doc):
        while self.pat_nr >= 0:
            doc = doc.replace(self.r_pat.format(self.pat_nr), self.pat, 1)
            self.pat_nr -= 1
        return doc


dmke = DoubleMergeKeyEnabler()

with open('test.yaml') as fp:
  # we don't do this line by line, that would not work well on flow style mappings
  orgdoc = fp.read()
  doc = dmke.convert(orgdoc)

data = yaml.load(doc)
data['questions'][0].anchor.always_dump = True
#######################################
# >>>> do your thing on data here <<< #
#######################################

with open('output.yaml', 'w') as fp:
    yaml.dump(data, fp, transform=dmke.revert)

res = subprocess.check_output(['diff', '-u', 'test.yaml', 'output.yaml']).decode('utf-8')
print('diff says:', res)
```

which gives:

```
diff says:
```

which means the files are the same on round-trip (as long as you don't
change anything before dumping).

Setting `preserve_quotes` and calling `ident()` on the `YAML` instance are necessary to 
preserve your superfluous quotes, resp. keeping the indentation.

Since the anchor `question-one` has no alias, you need to enable dumping explicitly by
setting `always_dump` on that attribute to True. If necessary you can recursively
walk over `data` and set `anchor.always_dump = True` when `.anchor.value is not None`

Comment: thx it goes through with my files and I'm testing it now in the application. One question, wouldn't it be easier to generate the file with `<<: [* ref1, * re]` and then in a second step just read the file and replace that part?

Comment: I don't thinks so. First of all newer versions of ruamel.yaml will not even let you load the file and get the broken behaviour of collapsing merge keys, as that has been fixed. Second, pulling out the merge key from a round-trip-loaded YAML file is possible, but significantly more complex. If your **real** data has anchors for all of the aliases, you should remove the "*" from the value of `self.pat`, otherwise your anchors might get lost when there is no reference after loading.

Comment: i've checked it and there seems to be 3 problems: 1. In my version I have quotes, like `title: "title test"` but using your solution the `""` is missing. 2. The`&question-one` is missing. 3. There is no indentation, as after `questions:` the `-` should be indented. Probably because of the missing `&question-one`. Btw I've updated my question. I've showed you just some parts of the file. now you see the complete one. Not sure if it makes a difference (really new to ruamel.yaml). Again, many thanks for your help

Comment: 1. set preserve_quotes 2. there is nothing that references that anchor, so these  are normally deleted as they have no function 3. Asking on SO is no substitute for [reading the documentation](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/detail.html#indentation-of-block-sequences)